# Validating a predicted standard deviation

Tags: variance, validation

I would like to validate the standard deviation which a model reports, because I think it is underestimated, because in the procedure some model selection is involved.

After running the model on a validation set, it became clear to me that the standard deviation were indeed grossly underestimated.

I could not really find a good way to prove this, but I think the clearest way to illustrate is a qqplot, which I generated using R:

```
qqnorm((m-v)/sd,ylim=c(-5,5))
```

with

- v (validation set)
- m (model prediction)
- sd (predicted standard
  deviation)

And which looks like (yes, I know it is really bad):

[image: qqplot]

Although I  find this graph very clear, it seems I was the only one in the lab, so I was wondering if anyone has suggestions on how I could plot/prove this more clearly. Also references on the topic are welcome, I made up this derivation myself because I could not find studies where also the predicted standard deviation was checked using a validation set.

Answer (score 1):

You qq plot is reasonable and looks very convincing, but you could also do a test of the variances (`var.test` in R, or `sigma.test` in the `TeachingDemos` package).  If the model selectino process does not bias estimates then we would expect the differences in the variances between the fit and validations sets to be only due to chance, which the variance test would explore.

Comment: No, these test will not work: the (predicted) standard deviation is different for every prediction.

Comment: @johanvdw you could combine what you did with the qqplot and the one sample variance test.  Subtract and divide like you did for the qqplot, the resulting values should have standard deviation of 1 if the predictions and standard deviations are correct, so just do the `sigma.test` with a null of 1.  You should probably check this out using simulation (generate data, split into 2 groups, estimate without the model selection, then do the analysis).